# Can't print nested JSON data with Angular 6

Tags: json, angular, typescript, nested, ngfor

I'm learning to code and just ran into this issue with Angular 6 which I can't seem to solve. I was able to get JSON's data before but now that it's nested I don't know how to get it's data. This is what I've done so far

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
    url = "http://localhost:80/assets/data/test.json";
    constructor(private http:Http) { }

    getTestWithObservable(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(this.url)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body;
    }

    private handleErrorObservable (error: Response | any) {
        console.error(error.message || error);
        return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { TestService } from './test.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'ngx-test',
    styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    observableTest: Observable<any>
    errorMessage: String;

    constructor(private testService: TestService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.testService.getTestWithObservable().subscribe(
            res => {
                let user = res[0]["users"];
                let user_data = user["data"];
                console.log(user_data["name"]);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

JSON

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "users": {
        "user_id": 14,
        "data": [{
            "name": "James",
            "age": 20
        },
        {
            "name": "Damien",
            "age": 25
        }]
    }
}]
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let x of user_data; let i = index">
    {{x.name}}
</div>
```

I'd appreciate if someone can point me out the solution or what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: are you getting data when console.log?

Comment: `user_data` is an array, so you need `user_data[0]["name"]` (although there is no reason the use square bracket syntax for the property, may as well do `user_data[0].name`)

Comment: this.user_data=res[0].users.data. Explain: res is an Array, res[0] is an object that have users property. users property has a property data that is the array you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the data in an instance property to access it. `user_data` is local to your function, you cannot access it in the template so you should use something like this :

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    observableTest: Observable<any>
    errorMessage: String;
    user_data: any;

    constructor(private testService: TestService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.testService.getTestWithObservable().subscribe(
            res => {
                let user = res[0]['users'];
                let user_data = user['data'];
                console.log(user_data['name']);
                this.user_data = user_data; // here
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Every double quotation should be change into single quote marks as "users" -> 'users'

Answer (score 0):

There is some problems with your code:

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  observableTest: Observable<any>
  errorMessage: String;

  user_data: any;

  constructor(private testService: TestService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.testService.getTestWithObservable().subscribe(
      res => {
        let user = res[0]["users"];
        this.user_data = user["data"];
        console.log(user_data["name"]);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

In Angular >= 4, **pipe methods** is better to handle Observable

```
this.http.get(this.url)
  .pipe(
    filter(...),
    map(...)
  )
```

With **HttpClient**  (Http is deprecated), the .json() is done for you. You don't need your extractData function.

- You have to initialize your variable. And use "this" to refer to it.

Comment: The OP's code isn't using `HttpClient`, so `extractData` is needed. That said, the code should almost definitely be updated to use `HttpClient`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've already choose the correct answer but yeah, that was the problem. Many thanks